# How can I auto load multiple images from a local folder using javascript/jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image, gallery, offline

I'm trying to build an offline image viewer (maybe manager too, but later). So I would like to automatically load multiple images from a folder, without declaring them on html (i.e., without using  for each image).
Is it possible using only javascript/jquery and **no** server-side languages (e.g., php)?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't clearly know but I don't think you can actually read files using javascript . At least on the client side using raw javascript . You can however upload some files and then store it inside that specific app you are building

The main reason you can't do it in Javascript from the client side is because it would be risky for normal users , any javascript developers could hack into user's file system via creating a client side javascript exploit

If you want to upload files using raw vanilla javascript , you can do it like this ...

```html
<input id="image-file" type="file" />
```

Then handle it via javascript like this

```
document.getElementById("image-file").addEventListener('onclick', function(e){
  const file = e.target.files[0];
  // your code
})
```

but if you really want to load images from a specific directory , you have to use a server side language like **Node.js** , you can learn to do it like [this](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html)

Comment: I understand your point. Of course, if javascript could get into someone's local folders it'll be a real mess... sorry for the silly question, I'm not a developer, just a DIY person ;). I'll try these two suggestions. Thank you very much for your help (and fast help!) and for being so kind and clear. Have a great week, Adib Mohsin!

Answer (score 0):

You can make a desktop application from a javascript project with electronjs. You can read and manipulate files too.

For example VSCode, or Spotify made the same way.

Check https://electronjs.org/ if interested.

There are some good youtube videos too to start from scratch. It's a little time investment to learn about it and start a basic project, but if you have a basic javascript knowlege, than it can be a good starting point.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this approch, if you only want to show the images on page. This is just a basic example, you can provide styles and much more to make it attractive.
If you also want to save it loacally, you can use local storage.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script 

src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$('#image-file').change(function(e){
for(let i=0;i<e.target.files.length;i++)
{
  let file = e.target.files[i];

$("body").append('<img src="'+URL.createObjectURL(file)+'">');


}
});
});


</script>
</head>
<body>
<input id="image-file" type="file" multiple/>

</body>
</html>
```